# Add VueJS directive dynamically from within another directive

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I would like to abstract as much as possible the binding of a form control to vuejs. The idea is to create a directive that will bind all events required to track what happens to a form field.

So instead of doing this:

```html
<input type="text" name="firstName" 
v-model="form.firstName.value" 
@blur="form.firstName.onBlur" 
@focus="form.firstName.onFocus" 
@change="form.firstName.onChange"
[...]
 />
```

simply do this:

```html
<input type="text" name="firstName" v-form-control="form.firstName" />
```

And let the directive do the magic.

But I can't find a way to add a directive to the input from within the `FormControl` directive.

I could do something like this:

```js
Vue.directive('form-control', {
    bind: function(el: HTMLElement, binding: DirectiveBinding) {
        const formControl: FormControl = binding.value;
        el.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
            formControl.updateValue(event.target.value);
        });
    },
});
```

But I lose a lot from VueJS by going this way.
I attach manually an `input` event which is not very compatible and will surely fail far more often than the `v-model` directive.

Do you know a way to attach the original vue directives and events to the element from the `bind` method of a directive?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The original Vue directives are literally event-handlers. V-model is syntactic sugar around `:value=".."` and `@input=".."`.

Hence, just go ahead and attach your eventlisteners for regular dom-events (input, blur, focus, change)

To be understood by the JavaScript runtime, Vue directives are translated into regular eventlisteners - they do not exist at runtime, hence, you cannot use their syntax dynamically at runtime.